# Merge matrices from two lists in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, merge

Suppose I have two lists that include several matrices. The first list includes matrices with dimensions that differ from matrix to matrix:

Code to create list1:

```
d<-c(0,1,0,1)
e<-c(1,0,0,0)
f<-c(0,0,0,0)
g<-c(1,0,0,0)
cn<-c(1,2,3,4)
p<-data.frame(d,e,f,g)
dimnames(p)<-list(cn,cn)

d<-c(0,1,0,1,0)
e<-c(1,0,0,0,0)
f<-c(0,0,0,0,0)
g<-c(1,0,0,0,1)
h<-c(0,0,0,1,0)
cn<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
q<-data.frame(d,e,f,g,h)
dimnames(q)<-list(cn,cn)

list1<-list(p,q)
names(list1)<-1990:1991
```

List1:

```
list1

$`1990`
  1 2 3 4
1 0 1 0 1
2 1 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 1 0 0 0

$`1991`
  1 2 3 4 5
1 0 1 0 1 0
2 1 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0
4 1 0 0 0 1
5 0 0 0 1 0
```

The second list includes matrices that always have the same dimensions and include all cases that ever occur in the matrices of List1 (6,7 would occur in additional matrices in list1).

Code to produce list2:

```
o<-matrix(NA,nrow=7,ncol=7)
dimnames(o)<-list(1:7, 1:7)
list2<-list(o,o)
names(list2)<-1990:1991
```

List2:

```
list2
$`1990`
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

$`1991`
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What I would like to do is to replace the NA's in list2 with, if available, the values from the respective matrix from list1, so that the result looks like this:

```
$`1990`
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  0  1  0  1 NA NA NA
2  1  0  0  0 NA NA NA
3  0  0  0  0 NA NA NA
4  1  0  0  0 NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

$`1991`
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  0  1  0  1  0  NA NA
2  1  0  0  0  0  NA NA
3  0  0  0  0  0  NA NA
4  1  0  0  0  1  NA NA
5  0  0  0  1  0  NA NA
6  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I suppose there is a way to do this by using the merge command. However, I have not figured any solution out yet, so any input is highly welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good opportunity to use `Map` (you have `data.frame` in your first list, convert them in `matrix` first!):

```
lst1 = lapply(list1, data.matrix)

> Map(function(m,p) {m[1:nrow(p),1:ncol(p)]=p;m}, list2, lst1)
$`1990`
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  0  1  0  1 NA NA NA
2  1  0  0  0 NA NA NA
3  0  0  0  0 NA NA NA
4  1  0  0  0 NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

$`1991`
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  0  1  0  1  0 NA NA
2  1  0  0  0  0 NA NA
3  0  0  0  0  0 NA NA
4  1  0  0  0  1 NA NA
5  0  0  0  1  0 NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

As per @akrun suggestion, a more generalist solution:

```
f = function(A,B)
{
    A[row.names(A) %in% row.names(B), colnames(A) %in% colnames(B)]=B
    A
}

Map(f, list2, lapply(list1, data.matrix))
```

Comment: instead of 1:nrow, 1:ncol, a more general approach would be to match the row.names/colnames between corresponding datasets especially when the names are not ordered.

Comment: I have just realized that I have some matrices in list1 that actually contain cases that are not included in list2. The matrices in list1 sometimes also have larger dimensions than the matrices in list2. In these cases, the code doesn't work. I want to keep the size of my standard matrices. How would I need to change the function, so that it also works in this situation?

Comment: Your comment contains a lot of questions, different from the initial. Can you open a second thread? Moreover, it's important to mention if you want to keep the size of the second list (thus troncate the size in lst1 if they have larger dimensions) or on the contrary you want to extend the length of the matrix in the second list...