# Merge matrices from one list on matrices from another one in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have asked a similar question before see ([Merge matrices from two lists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176583/merge-matrices-from-two-lists-in-r)). However, in contrast to my previous question, in this case:

1. I have matrices in list1 that have smaller, larger or equally sized dimensions as the standard matrices in list2.
2. Some of the matrices in list1 contain cases that are not included in list2.

In the following, you'll find the detailed question:

Suppose I have two lists that include several matrices. The first list includes matrices with dimensions that differ from matrix to matrix:

Code to create list1:

```
d<-c(0,1,0,1)
e<-c(1,0,0,0)
f<-c(0,0,0,0)
g<-c(1,0,0,0)
cn<-c(1,2,7,4)
p<-data.frame(d,e,f,g)
dimnames(p)<-list(cn,cn)
p<-as.matrix(p)

d<-c(0,0,0,1,1)
e<-c(0,0,1,0,0)
f<-c(0,1,0,0,0)
g<-c(1,0,0,0,0)
h<-c(1,0,0,0,0)
cn<-c(1,5,3,2,4)
q<-data.frame(d,e,f,g,h)
dimnames(q)<-list(cn,cn)
q<-as.matrix(q)

d<-c(0,1,0,1,0,0)
e<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0)
f<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1)
g<-c(1,0,0,0,1,0)
h<-c(0,0,0,1,0,0)
i<-c(0,0,1,0,0,0)
cn<-c(1,2,3,6,8,9)
r<-data.frame(d,e,f,g,h,i)
dimnames(r)<-list(cn,cn)
r<-as.matrix(r)

list1<-list(p,q,r)
names(list1)<-1990:1992
```

list1:

```
$`1990`
  1 2 7 4
1 0 1 0 1
2 1 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0
4 1 0 0 0

$`1991`
  1 5 3 2 4
1 0 0 0 1 1
5 0 0 1 0 0
3 0 1 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0 0
4 1 0 0 0 0

$`1992`
  1 2 3 6 8 9
1 0 1 0 1 0 0
2 1 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 1
6 1 0 0 0 1 0
8 0 0 0 1 0 0
9 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

The second list includes matrices that always have the same dimensions. The matrices from list1 can be smaller, larger or equally sized as the matrices in list2. Furthermore, the standard matrices from list2 sometimes contain not all cases from the respective matrices in lst1.

Code to produce list2:

```
o<-matrix(NA,nrow=5,ncol=5)
dimnames(o)<-list(1:5, 1:5)
list2<-list(o,o,o)
names(list2)<-1990:1992
```

list2:

```
$`1990`
   1  2  3  4  5
1 NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA

$`1991`
   1  2  3  4  5
1 NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA

$`1992`
   1  2  3  4  5
1 NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA
```

What I would like to do is to replace the NA's in list2 with, if available, the values from the respective matrix from list1. The dimensions of the matrices from list2 should remain unchanged during the process. The result should look like this:

```
$`1990`
   1  2  3  4  5 
1  0  1 NA  1 NA
2  1  0 NA  0 NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA
4  1  0 NA  0 NA
5 NA NA NA NA NA

$`1991`
   1  2  3  4  5
1  0  1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  1  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  1  0  0

$`1992`
   1  2  3  4  5
1  0  1  0  NA NA
2  1  0  0  NA NA
3  0  0  0  NA NA
4  NA NA NA NA NA
5  NA NA NA NA NA
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map` is still the way to go, just update the function and sort your first list by `colnames` and `row.names`:

```
list11 = lapply(list1, function(u){
            m=data.matrix(u)
            m[order(as.integer(row.names(m))),order(as.integer(colnames(m)))]
     })

f = function(A,B)
{
    A[row.names(A) %in% row.names(B), colnames(A) %in% colnames(B)]=B[row.names(B) %in% row.names(A), colnames(B) %in% colnames(A)]
    A
}

Map(f, list2, list11)

#$`1990`
#   1  2  3  4  5
#1  0  1 NA  1 NA
#2  1  0 NA  0 NA
#3 NA NA NA NA NA
#4  1  0 NA  0 NA
#5 NA NA NA NA NA

#$`1991`
#  1 2 3 4 5
#1 0 1 0 1 0
#2 1 0 0 0 0
#3 0 0 0 0 1
#4 1 0 0 0 0
#5 0 0 1 0 0

#$`1992`
#   1  2  3  4  5
#1  0  1  0 NA NA
#2  1  0  0 NA NA
#3  0  0  0 NA NA
#4 NA NA NA NA NA
#5 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: My approach is similar but I posted it as I was working on it and also some elements of your solution is not matching the expected output

Comment: hum there's an issue because the colnames and row.names in the first list are unordered. Solved!

Comment: The main function is quite often not the big problem, but the data in input ^ ^ Thks for your eagle eyes anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar approach as @Colonel Beauvel's solution but with `match`

```
  f1 <- function(x,y) {rInd1 <- match(row.names(x), row.names(y))
           rInd2 <- match(row.names(y), row.names(x))
           cInd1 <- match(colnames(x), colnames(y))
           cInd2 <- match(colnames(y), colnames(x))
           x[rInd1[!is.na(rInd1)], cInd1[!is.na(cInd1)]] <- 
                   y[rInd2[!is.na(rInd2)], cInd2[!is.na(cInd2)]]
       x}

  Map(f1, list2, list1)
  # $`1990`
  #   1  2  3  4  5
  #1  0  1 NA  1 NA
  #2  1  0 NA  0 NA
  #3 NA NA NA NA NA
  #4  1  0 NA  0 NA
  #5 NA NA NA NA NA

 #$`1991`
 #  1 2 3 4 5
 #1 0 1 0 1 0
 #2 1 0 0 0 0
 #3 0 0 0 0 1
 #4 1 0 0 0 0
 #5 0 0 1 0 0

 #$`1992`
 #  1  2  3  4  5
 #1  0  1  0 NA NA
 #2  1  0  0 NA NA
 #3  0  0  0 NA NA
 #4 NA NA NA NA NA
 #5 NA NA NA NA NA
```